# Intermittent network timeouts while trying to fetch data in Node application

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

We have a NextJS app with an Express server.

The problem we're seeing is lots of network timeouts to the API we are calling (the underlying exception says "socket hangup"). However, that API does not show any errors or a slow response time. It's as if the API calls aren't even making it all the way to the API.

Theories and things we've tried:

- Blocked event loop: we tried replacing synchronous logging with asynchronous "winston" framework, to make sure we're not blocking the event loop. Not sure what else could be blocking
- High CPU: the CPU can spike up to 60% sometimes. We're trying to minimize that spike by taking out some regexes we were using (since we heard those are expensive, CPU-wise).
- Something about how big the JSON response is from the API? We're passing around a lot of data…
- Too many complex routes in our Express routing structure: We minimized the number of routes by combining some together (which results in more complicated regexes in the route definitions)…

Any ideas why we would be seeing these fetch timeouts? They only appear during load tests and in production environments, but they can bring down the whole app with heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

The [code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_client.js#L345) that emits the error:

```
function socketCloseListener() {
  const socket = this;
  const req = socket._httpMessage;
  debug('HTTP socket close');

  // Pull through final chunk, if anything is buffered.
  // the ondata function will handle it properly, and this
  // is a no-op if no final chunk remains.
  socket.read();

  // NOTE: It's important to get parser here, because it could be freed by
  // the `socketOnData`.
  const parser = socket.parser;
  const res = req.res;
  if (res) {
    // Socket closed before we emitted 'end' below.
    if (!res.complete) {
      res.aborted = true;
      res.emit('aborted');
    }
    req.emit('close');
    if (res.readable) {
      res.on('end', function() {
        this.emit('close');
      });
      res.push(null);
    } else {
      res.emit('close');
    }
  } else {
    if (!req.socket._hadError) {
      // This socket error fired before we started to
      // receive a response. The error needs to
      // fire on the request.
      req.socket._hadError = true;
      req.emit('error', connResetException('socket hang up'));
    }
    req.emit('close');
```

The message is generated when the server does not send and response.
That's that easy bit.

But why would the API server not send a response?
Well, without seeing the minimum code that repro this I can only give you some pointers.

This [issue here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13461) discusses at length the changes between version 6 and 8, in particular how a GET with a body now can cause it. This change of behaviour is more aligned to the REST specs.

Comment: What if we're on Node v11? Also I mentioned I saw socket hangups, but also very often we just see `reason: connect ETIMEDOUT`

Comment: That code is from current master. For the ETIMEDOUT, it's a new piece of information, so feel free to ask another question. Or extend this one if you believe that these two errors have common cause.